# Share on Facebook IOS 11 Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, share, ios11

In versions below 11 ShareButton to facebook works successfull, but in 11 version this function doesn't work. What can u advice?

```
if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook) {
        var vc: SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        vc.setInitialText("My text")
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: You should use UIActivityViewController if you don't have your own share extension

Comment: Look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879798/about-slcomposeviewcontroller-in-ios-11-beta  might be helpful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the facebook sdk to share content
Like

> Step 1:

install pod :-   `pod 'FacebookShare'`

> Step 2:

import FBSDKShareKit

> Step 3:

```
func shareTextOnFaceBook() {
    let shareContent = ShareLinkContent()
    shareContent.contentURL = URL.init(string: "https://developers.facebook.com")! //your link
    shareContent.quote = "Text to be shared"
    ShareDialog(fromViewController: self, content: shareContent, delegate: self).show()
}

func sharer(_ sharer: Sharing, didCompleteWithResults results: [String : Any]) {
    if sharer.shareContent.pageID != nil {
        print("Share: Success")
    }
}
func sharer(_ sharer: Sharing, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Share: Fail")
}
func sharerDidCancel(_ sharer: Sharing) {
    print("Share: Cancel")
}
```

> Step 4: Must add this in `Info.plist`

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
</array>
```

Comment: In Step 3 Callback is not working, any ideas on how to solve?

Comment: @Balaach You should add "SharingDelegate" delegate.

Answer (score 3):

All of social constants (facebook, twitter, LinkedIn and others) have been deprecated on iOS 11 .

See here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/social/social_constants

You can use the FBSDKShareKit for the sharing function on facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios/

Answer (score 0):

Now it's more easy and more reliable to share media in facebook using FBSDKShareKit. You can follow the link below for details tutorial.

[Facebook, Messenger - Photo, Video, Link sharing in iOS Swift.](https://mahmudul-razib.medium.com/facebook-messenger-photo-video-link-sharing-in-ios-swift-465ef1388471)