# SLServiceTypeFacebook' was deprecated in iOS 11.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios11, swift4

I'm working on a project in xcode 9 and one of my previous codes giving a warning saying the code is been deprecated, where it does not trigger the action. The code as bellow. How can i overcome this ?

```
@IBAction func shareOnFacebookButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let shareToFacebook : SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    shareToFacebook.add(UIImage(named:"pureLightSocial"))
    self.present(shareToFacebook, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879798/about-slcomposeviewcontroller-in-ios-11-beta

Comment: Possible duplicate of [About "SLComposeViewController" in iOS 11 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879798/about-slcomposeviewcontroller-in-ios-11-beta)

Answer (score 13):

The `Facebook`, `Twitter`, and Other apps options have been removed in the `Settings` app.

That apps will now be treated like other apps, using the iOS `sharing extensions`

```
let share = [image, text, url]
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: share, applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You can also use third party `SDK` for individual sharing

[Facebook Sharing Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing)

[Twitter Sharing Doc](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/migrate-social-framework)

Comment: Sorry didn't understand?

Comment: as in this doesnt allows to share the content (image and a short description) using the browser as SLComposeViewController allows. I need away to share it as SLComposeViewController does it. but now seems its not working since its been deprecated

Comment: Then you have only one option that goes with the sdk and graph api of facebook.

Comment: Share extensions has own functionality and its built in so you did not change it. Let me check for sdk sharing.

Comment: Sadly, since this answer was written, Twitter have also now discontinued their support of Twitter Kit, which removes yet another option: https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/topics/tools/2018/discontinuing-support-for-twitter-kit-sdk.html

Comment: It looks like Twitter's API endpoints are the expected alternative now: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/overview