# About "SLComposeViewController" in iOS 13, Xcode 11 GM

Tags: ios, ios13, slcomposeviewcontroller

In my project, I always use `SLComposeViewController` to share contents with third-party apps, but now, when I update my iPhone to iOS 13 GM, this no longer works.

The `SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler` always callback `SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled`.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SLComposeViewController has been deprecated since iOS 11. You can either use Social Media's SDK or UIActivityViewController.

Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47054319/7677455)