# Swift - SLComposeViewController automatically dismissing itself

Tags: ios, swift, slcomposeviewcontroller

I am using `SLComposeViewController` for social sharing of photos.But i am getting this error in log

> SLComposeViewController automatically dismissing itself

My code:-

```
@IBAction func fbshare(_ sender:UIButton) {
    let vc = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    vc?.add(img.image!)
    vc?.add(URL(string: "http://www.example.com/"))
    vc?.setInitialText("Initial text here.")
    self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I am not able to get the `SLComposeViewController` on my screen.

Comment: There is no support from iOS11

Comment: is there any replacement for this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879798/about-slcomposeviewcontroller-in-ios-11-beta

Comment: @YashR Good to use provided default share sheet for sharing feature i.e. UIActivityViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working and for SLServiceTypeFacebook too but need to dismiss one to present the other. I am still working that out.

```
if let vc = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter) {

        //SLServiceTypeFacebook
        //SLServiceTypeTwitter

        vc.setInitialText(self.writeDBString)
        //vc.add(UIImage(named: "myImage.jpg")!)
        vc.add(URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app"))
        present(vc, animated: true )            
}
```